Optimize reading of a very wide dataset (100k columns) in polars and pandas
I have a dataset that contains a very large number of columns, about 500k.
The same data is stored in parquet and as a CSV.
I've noticed the following:

Reading the CSV file is very fast in polars, but crashes in pandas.
Reading the parquet file is very fast in pandas (about 30 seconds), but takes 30 minutes in polars.

# File paths. Both files contain the same data. Data contains 100k columns.
parquet_path = '.....'
csv_path = '.....'

import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

data_pl_parquet = pl.read_parquet(parquet_path) # Takes ages, about 30 minutes
data_pl_csv = pl.read_csv(csv_path) # Very fast, takes 30 seconds

data_pd_parquet = pd.read_parquet(parquet_path) # Very fast, takes 30 seconds
data_pd_csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path) # Takes more than 30 minutes then crashes

# What about reading the parquet in pandas, then converting it to polars?
pl.from_pandas(data_pd_parquet) # Takes 30 seconds


What's going on? Why do pandas and polars have such different behaviours? How can I debug this further?

pandas doesn't have a native parquet reader, it just uses pyarrow. Polars has a use_pyarrow parameter in read_parquet that if you set to True will use it instead of its own parquet reader thereby saving the pandas overhead with zero copy. In terms of debugging, it's most certainly at the rust level and you should submit a bug report with, if not the actual parquet, at least its schema and which writer wrote it. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues

I managed to reproduce this but if you have any details to add please do. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18319

This is fixed by this PR so it'll be in the the next version after 1.5.0
